# Con C# y Visual Studio, tengo un textBox en el que no se me quedan los datos que muestro en el mismo

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, textbox

Estoy con visual studio y C#. Tengo creado un textBox en un panel de la siguiente forma:

```
            this.textBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
            this.textBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            this.textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1455, 43);
            this.textBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.textBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 800);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 180;
            this.textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

El programa, al pulsarse el botón de Test tiene que mostrar "Test iniciado..." y al pulsar " el botón Etiqueta tiene que mostrar "Etiquetando" sin borrar lo anterior. Pero cuando pulso uno u otro botón se me sobreescribe lo último.

Las funciones que tengo son para etiqueta:

```
private void button_Etiqueta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Etiquetando...\r\n";
        }
```

Para Test:

```
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Test iniciado...\r\n";

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que te borra lo anterior porque eso estas especificando, lo que tienes que hacer es usar una variable e ir concatenando tus valores.

Declarar esta variable fuera de los metodos para que ambos la consuman y no la vuelvan a dejar vacia.

```
    string mensaje = string.Empty;

    private void button_Etiqueta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mensaje =  "Etiquetando...\r\n";
        textBox1.Text = mensaje;
    }
```

Para Test:

```
    {
        mensaje += "Test iniciado...\r\n";
        textBox1.Text = mensaje;

    }
```

Edicion:
Puede hacer lo mismo usando:

```
        textBox1.Text += "Test iniciado...\r\n";
```

Comment: Sin la variable, funciona de la misma forma ;) se puede hacer textBox1.Text += "texto", ya que la propiedad Text del control, es en si, una variable dentro de la clase que maneja ese control ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias, no lo tenia en cuenta.

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi. Estaba buscando en las propiedades del textBox a ver si había alguna opción que permitiera almacenar la info en el textBox, pero tu solución me gusta más y es más sensata XD

Comment: @JotaCeb recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio!!!!

Comment: Perdona XD. Muchas gracias!! Aceptada!